# Controller Creation Exception

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am getting Controller Creation Exception When rendering controller in sitecore. Please see screen shots below:

Layout where exception is thrown:

[image]

Footer Controller Code:

[image]

Base Controller Code:

[image]

Sitecore Controller Rendering:

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong, Can someone suggest what could be the issue and a fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you just put your "controller name" in controller.

```
Controller: Footer
Controller Action: RenderFooter
```